# Expo Build:ios Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to build my expo app for ios following expo documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/?redirected#if-you-choose-to-build-for-ios). I have successfully published to expo and I have successfully built for android through the expo-cli. I am able to login to the Apple Developer dashboard so I know I have the correct login and password. When I run  `expo build:ios` it returns

```
Authenticating to Apple Developer Portal...
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
bash exited with non-zero code: 1
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    ...                                                                                                              pawn-async\src\spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at spawnAsync (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\src\spawnAnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at runAction (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\appleApi\fastlane.ts:20:28)           oent.js:34:29)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\appleApi\authenticate.ts:49:46)    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Context.ensureAppleCtx (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\credentials\context.ts:8181:24)                                                                                                               sync.ts:26:19)
    at IOSBuilder.bestEffortAppleCtx (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\iosos\IOSBuilder.ts:95:14)
    at IOSBuilder.prepareCredentials (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\iosos\IOSBuilder.ts:151:5)                                                                                              :24)
    at IOSBuilder.run (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\ios\IOSBuilder.ts:\IOSBuilder.ts:95:14)s:62:7)                                                                                                              \IOSBuilder.ts:151:5)
    at IOSBuilder.command (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\build\BaseBuilder.ts62:7)ts:39:7)                                                                                                             :39:7)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jaxbl\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:346:7)
```

Running `expo diagnostics` I get

```
  Expo CLI 4.0.4 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.18.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 6.14.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  4.1.0.0 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^40.0.0 => 40.0.0
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2
      react-navigation: ^4.4.3 => 4.4.3
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

I have made sure WSL2 is enabled, I have Ubuntu installed and running, I have run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` from an Admin Powershell. In my bios SVM is enable, Hyper-V is turned on.

I have tried running `expo build:ios` from command prompt, Powershell, Admin Powershell with the same results.

I have seen other people with issues because of a new Apple Developer account. The one I am using was created two days ago but it seems like that should have been long enough that it would work.

I'm not sure what I am missing at this point so any help figuring it out would be much appreciated.